# Use variables from properties file in a Maven Plugin

Tags: java, maven

I need to be able to use "variables" for a maven plugin like this:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jelastic</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jelastic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <api_hoster>${api_hoster}</api_hoster>
                        <email>${email}</email>
                        <password>${password}</password>
                        <environment>${environment}</environment>
                        <!--<context>[specify the context if you need it]</context>-->
                        <!--<comment>[insert comment if you need it]</comment>-->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Already have the properties file set in the base directory and have used the plugin:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <files>
                                    <file>${basedir}/jelastic.properties</file>
                                </files>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Still, the variables in the plugin cannot be resolved, what could be wrong here?

Comment: How do you declare your properties?

Comment: Insteed of using properities plugin, use profile and declare properties there. File content will be almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

You must either declare those variables as `<properties>` in project or profile or pass them as env variables like `mvn whatever -Dyourprop=value`

Read about properties: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties

Read about profiles: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Answer (score 1):

add those lines to your POM:

```
    <build>
    <resources>
    <resource>
    <includes>
    <include>**/*.properties</include>
    </includes>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
    </resources>
    </build>
```

And this properties file:

```
   api_hoster:${api_hoster}
   email:${email}
   password:${password}
   environment:${environment}
```

and invoke any maven plugin by mentioning a profile:

```
mvn clean -Pname
```

Comment: Which file and which part of the file?

Comment: your pom.xml in build section

Comment: Not allowed to do `<build><include>**/*.properties</include></build>`

Comment: Why would you want OP to actually include properties that are only required on compile time into build output?

Comment: did he mentioned that?

Comment: But did he have to? All stuff that are in POM and required there are compile time assets.

Comment: no he doesn't have to, maybe he needs to inject properties based on profile when it builds